# In MediaPipe, is it possible to see augmented landmarks rendered in real time?

Tags: mediapipe

So I am using MediaPipe Holistic Solutions to extract keypoints from a body, hands and face, and I am using the data from this extraction for my calculations just fine. The problem is, I want to see if my data augmentation works, but I am unable to see it in real time. An example of how the keypoints are extracted:

```
lh_arr = (np.array([[result .x, result .y, result .z] for result in results.left_hand_landmarks.landmark]).flatten()
```

if I then do lets say, lh_arr [10:15]*2, I cant use this new data in the draw_landmarks function, as lh_arr is not class 'mediapipe.python.solution_base.SolutionOutputs'. Is there a way to get draw_landmarks() to use an np array instead or can I convert the np array back into the correct format? I have tried to get get the flattened array back into a dictionary of the same format of results, but it did not work. I can neither augment the results directly, as they are unsupported operand types.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work with the landmarks in `numpy array`, then you can use:

```py
landmarks_np = np.array(results.pose_landmarks.landmark)
# perform some operations
landmarks_np[10].x = 0.2 # value in results.pose_landmarks is modified
```

In this case, you are actually modifying the landmarks in `results.pose_landmarks`, since they are *reference types*, so it is then enough to pass `results.pose_landmarks` to `draw_landmarks()` as usually.

Or you can simply modify the landmarks by accessing them through their indices:

```py
results.pose_landmarks.landmark[1].x = 0.95
results.pose_landmarks.landmark[1].y = 0.45
...
```

If for some reason you need to create `NormalizedLandmarkList`, you can use:

```py
from mediapipe.framework.formats import landmark_pb2
landmarks_modified = landmark_pb2.NormalizedLandmarkList(landmark = landmarks_np)
```

However, as you could see, it should be not required.